# Google maps does not show route when opened by link

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-urls

The link

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=60.626200,16.776800

results in a webpage with a map like this in on my computer
[image: Google maps route image]

When the link is clicked in an android browser, you will be offered to open it in the "Maps" app.

The app however will not care about the route and shows up like this:

[image: Output from the maps app]

Is it possible to have the route shown in "Maps" as well?

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2017 the recommended by Google method is the Google Maps URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

You can create a cross-platform universal URL for Google directions following the documentation. In your example the URL will be

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=60.626200,16.776800&travelmode=driving`

I tried this URL in desktop browser and on mobile, in both cases it worked pretty well.

Hope this helps!